# Lloyd's mirror problem

Tags: quantum-mechanics, optics, visible-light, waves, interference

My question is about the reflection of the interference pattern from the screen to the mirror itself in the(Image B), as you can see in the mirror the reflected interference pattern is similar to youngs classic interference pattern rather than the one which interferd on the screen..
why wouldn’t it be also shifted in the mirror as on the screen?

Why do you think this happens and how is it even possible?
(im a dentistry student not a physics student im just curious) [image][image][image]

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what you mean. What is the phenomenon that is puzzling you? The interference pattern with Lloyd's mirrors is the same as the Young pattern, but shifted, because the reflection adds a $\pi$ phase offset.

Comment: i understand that, but when i look at the reflected pattern that is reflected in the mirror itself from the screen, pattern is not shifted anymore, why is that?

Comment: Sorry again, but I'm still not sure about what you mean. Instead of looking at the screen, are you  looking at the mirror? Is that what you mean?

Comment: yes exactly, i also looked at the reflected pattern on the mirror, and it was not shifted but rather like Youngs pattern. simultaneously the pattern on the screen is shifted and on the mirror not shifted.

Comment: Then obviously there is a double reflection, and thus $2\pi$ phase shift, which equals no phase shift.

Comment: thank you for your answer, this was also my speculation but wasn’t sure.

Comment: I'll add a short anser, since nobody else has done it.

Comment: What is the source of the diagram? Please don't cut and paste random stuff on the internet without attribution. It's rude.

Comment: Please dont post uncontributional comments on unrelated subjects that satisfy your own sadistic criticism needs, it's badly Mannered. also the image is edited(notice drawn green lines), so i may not attribute it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each reflection introduces a phase shift of $180º$, or $\pi$ radians.

- When you look at the screen, the mirror ray suffers one reflection, and thus you see a shifted Young's pattern. This doesn't happen with other methods that have no mirrors.
- When you look into the mirror, the reflected ray from the screen has also suffered a phase shift. Since the relevant thing is the difference between the two, it doesn't affect anymore.

In the same way, 2 ideal reflections leave the ray invariant $(2\pi)$, and three reflections are like one.